# DirectX in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, directx-11

i have the following code in my C file in Visual Studio... it compiles alright but it hangs the computer in the DLL function call...

```
hr = D3D11CreateDevice(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL, 0, 0, 0, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &gamedevice, &featureLevel, &gamedevicecontext);
fprintf_s(debugfile, "called CreateDevice()...\n");
fflush(debugfile);
if( FAILED(hr) )
{
MessageBox(0, "D3D11CreateDevice Failed.", 0, 0);
return 0;
}
```

there is a whole lot more code following this but debugfile shows that it doesn't reach it... am i doing the right thing by using D3D11CreateDevice first in my app or do i need enum type code first? how do i debug a D3D DLL in Visual Studio?

i have been using the book '3d game programming using DirectX 11' by Frank D. Luna

hope you can help

Comment: This is not enough information since you didn't include where you declared all those types.

Answer (score 0):

Frank Luna's book was published about 3 minutes before the DirectX SDK was killed off, so a lot of his book refers to stuff you'd be better off not using like D3DX11. That said, there are plenty of good replacements. See [Where is the DirectX SDK (2015 Edition)?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/08/05/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2015-edition/), [Living without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/) and [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2014/04/07/book-recommendations/) for some specific notes.

For a detailed walkthrough of Direct3D 11 device creation, read [Anatomy of Direct3D 11 Create Device](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2014/02/05/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device/).

> As you are new to Direct3D 11, I'd recommend taking a look at the [DirectX Tool Kit tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).

Answer (score 0):

Frank Luna using in his book d3dx11 library, which is deprecated now. A lot of features were moved from that lib to d3d11.lib and dxgi.lib, which should be also included to your project, as well as dxgi.h header:

```
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <dxgi.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dxgi.lib")
```

P.S. And as [@Chuck Walbourn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3780494/chuck-walbourn) mentioned try DirectX Tool Kit